# Reading and Writing to the same file simultaneously in java

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

How can I access data in my file without first closing my BufferedWriter?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Tp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File f = new File("Store.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader(f));
        bw.write("Some text");
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
        bw.write("Some more text");
        bw.close();
        br.close();
    }
}
```

The console is showing null. How do I fix this?

Comment: You have to `flush()` the writer before you read

Comment: BufferedWriter does not operate with your disc after each write operations, it collects data in its buffer. flush() method is required to push your data to disc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have not flushed the stream

```
public class Tp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File f = new File("/path/to/your/file/filename.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new  FileReader(f));
    bw.write("Some text");
    bw.flush();
    System.out.println(br.readLine());
    bw.write("Some more text");
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
    br.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: please accept the answer if this resolve your problem